# Setting a timezone in vitest

Tags: testing, mocking, timezone, vitest

I would like to set (actually mock) a timezone in my Vitest tests to get deterministic results in all time zones they will run in.
I run my tests on a local machine and also in CI/CD environments that have different timezones.

I've searched for some answers on Stackoverflow but haven't found a good cleare way to do it in vitest.

Answer (score 8):

Create a file `vitest.global-setup.ts`

```
export const setup = () => {
  process.env.TZ = 'UTC'
}
```

Then add it to `globalSetup` in `vitest.config.ts`

```
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    globalSetup: './vitest.global-setup.ts',
    // ...
  },
```

(Solution found in [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/1575#issuecomment-1439286286))

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work on windows. works on the debian docker

Answer (score 1):

You can't "mock" the timezone directly. The closest you can get is to set the TZ environment variable when you run vitest.

For example: `TZ=UTC vitest`

I save this in my package.json as a script and then execute that script like this:

```json
{
  scripts: {
    test: "TZ=UTC vitest"
  }
}
```

And just run `yarn test` so I don't have to think about it. This gives me deterministic timezones. This plus a `vi.setSystemTime` should hopefully cover your needs.

If you need to test different timezones I don't think it is possible to do that within a test itself. You would have to run vitest multiple times with different environment variables.

See this issue for more information: https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/1575

vi.setSystemTime: https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-setsystemtime

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can mock the timezone, here's how to do it:

```js
    vi.spyOn(globalThis.Intl, 'DateTimeFormat').mockImplementation(() => ({
      resolvedOptions: () => ({
        timeZone: 'America/New_York', // Your timezone, rest is irrelevant
        calendar: 'gregory',
        locale: 'en-US',
        numberingSystem: 'latn',
      }),
      format: () => '1/1/2022',
      formatRange: () => '1/1/2022 – 1/1/2023',
      formatRangeToParts: () => [],
      formatToParts: () => [],
    }))
```